# How to have a specific 404 for a folder using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, http-status-code-404, file-not-found

This is a bit tricky and I'd be glad if you guys could give me some pointers on this one. 
Here is what I want to do:

- A user tries to access
  myapp.com/data/123456.mp3
- test.mp3 doesn't exist
- The system sends the user to
  myapp.com/data/error.apsx?file=123456.mp3

I need this in order to handle the way a large system is supposed to serve mp3 files.

If a user tries to access myapp.com/otherFolder/notHere.whatever, the system returns the standard 404 error normally.

I know there are ways to specify that in IIS, but I'd love it if there was something I could do programmatically or just withing my .net project.

edit:

I've created a web.config file in myapp.com/data/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/data/mp3/full/serveMp3.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: About the accepted answer: take a look at the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Errors
http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages.aspx

In your web.config.

```
<customErrors
       mode="RemoteOnly" 
       defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx" 
/>
```

Comment: all files not found.. the generalerror.aspx is the display page.

Comment: Also, this would work for the whole application and not only for a folder. I want to be able to specify on what folder it should apply

Comment: You can put a web.config in any folder which will override.

Comment: If Omu's answer is correct and you can put a web config in a file then it would work I suppose. I'm not sure how I should go and do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the question with what I did, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you viewing it on the server?

Comment: You can switch mode to "on" if you're not being redirected.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm seeing it on the server I have locally (asp.net development server)

Comment: it fixed it! (mode = on) Thanks! Do you know why remoteOnly was breaking it?

Comment: RemoteOnly means that you (viewing locally) will see the error, but your audience (remote) will see the nice happy redirect.

Comment: Also, I need the original file that have been called (in my example myapp.com/data/123456.mp3), can I retrieve it from GeneralError.aspx?

Comment: Oh nevermind it looks like it's in the url : errorpath=/data/fsdfsd.mp3

Comment: Well madcolor, thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. I'm really glad I can do it that way :)

Comment: If you want even more control you can write an HTTPmodule to do more manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to do is make sure ASP.NET gets to handle these file requests since by default .mp3 isn't an ASP.NET extension and this will just be handled by IIS.

Couple of ways to actually do this once you are handling it spring to mind.

The first is to create an HttpModule which watches the OnUnhandledException event. Since ASP.NET throws 404's (and all HTTP errors) as HttpException type exceptions the module will provide you with a place to catch, parse the request, and redirect to your own ends.

The other means is to create a web.config at the folder level you care about (these can be nested remember) and create customerror section there. This is more straightforward but affords much less control. All things considered I would favour the module generally.

Comment: I don't need control since it's 100% sure that this action will only be in this folder and will only do this one action. So I suppose I need to use the web config. I edited my question qith what I did

Answer (score 0):

probably you could put a web.config indide the folder that you want to put a specific error and put in that webconfig the customerror tag with the page indicated
or you can use the location tag inside the main web.config

but i'm not sure about this